# Android рисование Canvas

Tags: java, android, canvas

Как сделать так, чтобы при вводе числа `n` нарисовалось `n` кругов?
 
Я попытался сделать, но каждый круг приходится описывать вручную. Как все автоматизировать?
Вот код класса:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new DrawView(this));
}

class DrawView extends View {

    Paint p;
    Rect rect;
    StringBuilder sb;
    int count;
    int x;
    int y;
    int r;
    int offset;



    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        p = new Paint();
        rect = new Rect();
        sb = new StringBuilder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        x = canvas.getWidth() / 2;
        y = canvas.getHeight() / 2;
        r = 50;
        offset = 300;


        count = 4;

        canvas.drawARGB(80, 102, 204, 255);

        p.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        // толщина линии = 10
        p.setStrokeWidth(10);
        // рисуем точку (в центре)
        canvas.drawPoint(x, y, p);

        // рисуем круг с радиусом = 50
        canvas.drawCircle(x, y - offset, r, p);
        canvas.drawCircle(x + offset, y, r, p);
        canvas.drawCircle(x, y + offset, r, p);
        canvas.drawCircle(x - offset, y, r, p);

        // настраиваем размер текста = 30
        p.setTextSize(70);

        p.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
        p.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.drawText("1", x, y - offset + 30, p);
        canvas.drawText("2", x + offset, y + 30, p);
        canvas.drawText("3", x, y + offset + 30, p);
        canvas.drawText("4", x - offset, y + 30, p);
    }

}

}
```

Вот пример изображения, которое у меня получилось:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот, что получилось, но круги не в правильно порядке расставлены

```
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
            x = x0 + offset * Math.cos(114.592/count*i);
            y = y0 + offset * Math.sin(114.592/count*i);
            canvas.drawCircle((float) x, (float) (y - offset), r, p);
            p.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            canvas.drawText(Integer.toString(i + 1), (float)x, (float)y - offset + 25, p);
            p.setColor(Color.BLUE);

        }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
canvas.drawCircle(x, y, r, p);
canvas.drawText(n, x1, y1, p);
```

Загнать в цикл, где `x` и `y` будут изменяться по необходимым правилам , `n`, соответственно, счетчик цикла (+1).

Comment: а по каким правилам? как сделать так чтоб они в виде круга были, нужна какаято формула или как?

Comment: Простая формула для построения окружности. `x = x0 + R*cos a,  y = y0 + R*sin a`. `X0, y0` - координаты центра. `R` радиус, `а` - угол в радианах. Берете 2радиана, делите на количество элементов в цикле и умножаете на счётчик цикла.

Comment: если я правильно понял вас то как то так `for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
                x = x0 + offset * Math.cos(114.592/count*i);
                y = y0 + offset * Math.sin(114.592/count*i);
                canvas.drawCircle((float) x, (float) (y - offset), r, p);
                p.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                canvas.drawText(Integer.toString(i + 1), (float)x, (float)y - offset + 25, p);
                p.setColor(Color.BLUE);

            }` но все равно как то не по порядку идут круги

Comment: обновил вопрос, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: @java замените 114.592 на 6.28319

Comment: спасибо большое помогло)))))